# jQuery tabs not working in Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am making an application using `codeigniter`, my registration and login form is in a tab. when I click on the registration tab it is not displayed. The file paths for the js files are all correct because I have clicked on them in source code view and they are displayed.

form code

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="http://phpoll.com/login/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="http://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="http://phpoll.com/register/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/js/home.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery code

```
$('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
    $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
$('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
    $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
    $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
    $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/0rc7wmsg/.  may be forgot to add jquery

Comment: i have added jquery code

Comment: i m talking about jquery library.

Comment: i tried this code and it is working fine.Have you register `jquery.min.js`.As after adding it ,it is working and if still not working then their may be confliction in jquery.

Comment: iv added my jquery file links to the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working fine i check this code on my system may be you have not enter the file path correct

try this cdn links of js.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: iv added my jquery file links to the question box above it still does not work

Comment: plz check the base url at assets/js/home.js should it not added to your system.

Comment: the url is correct because when i go to view source code on a web browser the JavaScript links work

Comment: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: i fixed it i moved the jquery link above all the other jquery files and it worked thanks for your help